# cannot run osgi bundles outside eclipse

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I am making my firsts steps using osgi and I have a problem with a bundle I created.

I developed 3 bundles in eclipse (they are plugin projects). When I run my bundles inside eclipse using a new and empty target, they work very nice.

Then I tried to export them and run them without eclipse I ran with problems. I created a jar file for each one of them (using export ->deployable plugin) and then I install them in a running equinox container (v3.7.1, from eclipse's plugin directory) and I got a lot of ClassNotFoundExceptions for RuntimeErrorException

this looks like a classpath issue. I think I am not exporting the bundle correctly, but I am not sure.

The problem only happens with 2 of the bundles, which use additional libraries

how can I do it correctly?

In case you need it, this is the [full stack](http://pastebin.com/dHLDDfMn)

Comment: Could you please paste META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for each of those jars? I'm especially interested in Import-Package section. In my opinion either there is no bundle which exports this package in your OSGi container, or it is not present in Import-Package. It would be also very useful if you paste a list of exported packages for all bundles in you container (I have never worked with Equinox, but I guess this should do the trick: "vsh package list").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking one of the exceptions for example: NoClassDefFoundError on `javax.management.RuntimeErrorException`.

Did you import the package `javax.management` in your bundle?

See the following page from the OSGi Community Wiki, it seems directly relevant to your problem: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix%3F

Comment: thank you very much. I completely forgot that javax. classes are not treated the same as java. classes.

Comment: No classes are treated the same as `java.*` because `java.` is special. **All** other packages must be explicitly imported.